# sudo -u "user" --login vs. su "user" --login

Tags: sudo, users, su

I think there is slightly differencess between

```
sudo -u "user" --login
```

and

```
su "user" --login
```

For instance, I create a user with `useradd -m user` and ran `passwd -e` which means the user `user`'s password must be updated at first login.

What makes me confuse is if I do  `sudo -u "user" --login` there is no prompt telling to change the password at first login and it continues to login as a `user`. But if I do `su "user" --login` there is a prompt:

```
You are required to change your password immediately (administrator enforced)
Changing password for user.
Current password:
```

So what is differences between two?

Comment: Whose password do you enter for each?

Comment: it is the "user" password, the "user" here is a name of new created user @muru

Comment: You use the same user's password for both `sudo -u user` and `su user`? Which user are you using to run the commands?

Comment: for the sudo it use the "host" password and for su it use the "user" password so there is different password

Answer (score 1):

**Forget** and **never** use the second line, i.e. stick to
`$ sudo -u "user" --login`

It's because the second line syntax is **not** documented. *Please*, always:

- refer to the official documentation, and
- avoid undocumented syntaxes.

What's not written is *not* guaranteed to work, and *can change in future without notification*.